# Linux: tput cup with Lua acting strange

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, lua, text-cursor

In Lua, I'm trying to use the shell command 'tput cup foo bar' to move the cursor, and 'io.write('foo')' to write a string at that position.

```
os.execute('tput clear')    --clear terminal
os.execute('tput cup 2 9')  --move cursor to line 2, col 9
io.write('A')               --write 'A' at the cursor position
os.execute('tput cup 8 2')  --move cursor to line 8, col 2
io.write('B')               --write 'B' at the cursor position
```

However, for some reason, it prints both characters at the second cursor position (col 2, line 8).

When I use print() instead of io.write(), though, it prints both characters in their correct positions. I don't want to use print() for obvious reasons, so how can I make both strings be written in their correct positions with io.write()?

Comment: You probably need to call `io.flush()` after writing.

Comment: I tried this, made it so only the first string appeared ('A').

Answer (score 1):

You do need to call `io.flush()`. @lhf had the correct suggestion. But the trick is that you need it at the *right place* in the code.

```
os.execute('tput clear')    --clear terminal
os.execute('tput cup 2 9')  --move cursor to line 2, col 9
io.write('A')               --write 'A' at the cursor position
io.flush()                  --*** this is what was missing
os.execute('tput cup 8 2')  --move cursor to line 8, col 2
io.write('B')               --write 'B' at the cursor position
```

The output is going to the terminal, and there are two programs competing to write to the terminal: Lua and tput. The first two calls to `io.execute('tput')` write to the terminal right away. The call to `io.write()` puts the letter 'A' in Lua's internal output buffer. We must force this buffered output to go the terminal before we do the next call to `io.execute('tput')`.

In general, you should flush your program's output buffers before calling any external program that writes to the same output stream. Otherwise, output buffering will make things arrive in the output stream out-of-order.